# Using xstring IfStrEqCase and underscores causing problems

Tags: shell-escape, xstring, underscore

I'm using `xstring` (and `\IfStrEqCase`) to choose from a set of file paths (as the bellow example). I have two problems:

1. Even if package documentation states that underscore is allowed, if I introduce it the macro doesn't work (needs the escape `\`). (Example Case 1).
2. If I try to use the command `\dothis{0}` as argument for write it gives and error (missing `}`).

Can anyone help me on this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\dothis}[1]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{#1}{
        {0}{c:/Temp/myfile.txt}
        {1}{c:/Temp\_new/myfile.txt}    %require \ for underscore!!!
        {2}{c:/Temp/my-1file.txt}
        {3}{c:/Temp\_2/my-some-\_file2.txt}
        {4}{me@somewhere}
        }
    [nope]
}



\begin{document}

    % Test each option
    \dothis{0} \newline
    \dothis{1} \newline
    \dothis{2} \newline
    \dothis{3} \newline
    \dothis{4} \newline


\immediate\write18{copy /y c:/Temp/myfile.txt  c:/Temp/newtmp0.temp}

% Command not working:
%\immediate\write18{copy /y \dothis{0}  c:/Temp/newtmp1.temp


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your evaluation is integer-based and starts from 0. As such, it presents an ideal opportunity to use the *expandable* `\ifcase` switch:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\dothis}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 %
        c:/Temp/myfile.txt%             0
    \or c:/Temp\_new/myfile.txt%        1
    \or c:/Temp/my-1file.txt%           2
    \or c:/Temp\_2/my-some-\_file2.txt% 3
    \or me@somewhere%                   4
    \else nope%                         other
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

% Test each option
\dothis{0} \newline
\dothis{1} \newline
\dothis{2} \newline
\dothis{3} \newline
\dothis{4} \newline

\immediate\write17{copy /y c:/Temp/myfile.txt c:/Temp/newtmp0.temp}

\immediate\write17{copy /y \dothis{0} c:/Temp/newtmp1.temp}

\end{document}
```

The log outputs:

```
copy /y c:/Temp/myfile.txt c:/Temp/newtmp0.temp
copy /y c:/Temp/myfile.txt c:/Temp/newtmp1.temp
```

I use `\write17` to `\typeout` the execution. However, for `\write18` you should not escape `_` and therefore use

```
\newcommand{\dothis}[1]{%
  \ifcase#1 %
        c:/Temp/myfile.txt%           0
    \or c:/Temp_new/myfile.txt%       1
    \or c:/Temp/my-1file.txt%         2
    \or c:/Temp_2/my-some-_file2.txt% 3
    \or me@somewhere%                 4
    \else nope%                       other
  \fi
}
```

---

An equivalent LaTeX3 implementation:

```
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\dothis}{m}{%
  \int_case:nnF { #1 }
  {
    { 0 } { c:/Temp/myfile.txt }
    { 1 } { c:/Temp_new/myfile.txt }
    { 2 } { c:/Temp/my-1file.txt }
    { 3 } { c:/Temp_2/my-some-_file2.txt }
    { 4 } { me@somewhere }
  }
  { nope }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Since `_` is already treated differently under `\ExplSyntaxOn`, there is no need to escape it.

Comment: Underscores should not be escaped, if the purpose is using the paths in a `\write18` command

Comment: @egreg: Wow, that's ugly output! I've mentioned this in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Underscore is allowed in the strings to be compared. The rest is just normal TeX text, thus underscored must be escaped there, just like `$`, `&` and `#` etc.
2. `\IfStrEqCase`, like most if the macros of the package, is not expandable, and therefore cannot be used in a `\write`. So you must rewrite your macro to store the outcome in a macro (that you can pass as the second parameter). And then use that in the write.

```
\newcommand{\dothis}[2]{%
  \IfStrEqCase{#1}{
    {0}{\def#2{c:/Temp/myfile.txt}}
    {1}{\def#2{c:/Temp\_new/myfile.txt}}
    {2}{\def#2{c:/Temp/my-1file.txt}}
    {3}{\def#2{c:/Temp\_2/my-some-\_file2.txt}}
    {4}{\def#2{me@somewhere}}
    }
  [\def#2{nope}]
}

\dothis{0}{\Result}
\immediate\write18{copy /y \Result\space  c:/Temp/newtmp1.temp}
```

Comment: See [Why do code snippets not work after lists?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1558/5764)